# Trying to find ActionScript 3.0 files

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have been tasked with making some edits to a legacy system that is essentially a Flash game that has no documentation and the original author has long since left the company.  Unfortunately it is also using technologies I haven't touched in years (and even then it was in a university setting).

But enough of my woes.

I have found the `.fla` file and opened it up in `Adobe Flash Professional CS5`, I have started hunting for the action script snippets I need to edit and I suspect I actually have an incomplete `.fla` but I want to confirm.

To find where I need to edit I have tried clicking on each element on the stage and clicking F9 to open up the actions frame, when this came up with nothing (totally blank action script fields) I tried pressing Alt+F3 to bring up the Movie Explorer and have tried to hide everything bar ActionScript, again nothing.

Hopefully I am making a totally rookie mistake, but my knowledge and my searching have hit their limits.

**edit - additional information**

There is no Document Class assigned.

I have went through each MovieClip (using the Movie Explorer) but I can't see any reference to a Class (would this be instance name?)

Comment: And that is why I never liked the IDE...

Comment: @John - heh, that is semi-reassuring that I haven't just missed something obvious.

Comment: Have you checked the Document Class and the class of each MovieClip in the library? Ideally a proper AS3 project wouldn't have code on the timeline.

Comment: @Shane There is no Document Class assigned.  I have went through each MovieClip (using the Movie Explorer) but I can't see any reference to a Class (would this be instance name?) I will edit my original question with this thanks.

Comment: In the library, is there an AS Linkage defined alongside the name of your MovieClips? If so, that may correspond to external files. Otherwise you may be looking at an incomplete fla, possibly as the result of it being decompiled from an SWF without the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug the project (ctrl+shift+enter), all the code embedded in the .fla (that is, the action panel) will be enlisted for you to navigate in the debug panel.

I find it very hard that all the code would be embedded in the action panels though. Is the program old enough to have been made in AS2? Are you positive it`s AS3?

Comment: "You cannot debug this SWF because it does not contain ActionScript" - I think we have a winner! Thanks for your help. It is definitely AS3 (I was told this specifically) I am going to do some digging to see if I can find an external file, but it could have got lost a while ago.